# How to calculate total probability from independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Assume Y is caused by two independent events A & B, upon investigating a data set carrying 1000 entries we see.

> $$\begin{align}\text{Number of occurrence of events } A = 497 \text{ and } B=472.\\ \text{ Out of 497 occurrences of A, A causing Y to happen = 259 (A')and }\\ \text{ out of 472 occurrences of B, B causing Y to happen= 249 (B')} \end{align}$$

The observations says either A or B can cause Y and the number of times Y has happened = 381. Also joint distribution of $$\begin{align}Y|A \cap B = 127  \end{align}$$

So, If I rewrite the whole thing, this is what I see,

> $$\begin{array}{lrr}\\ 
> p(A) =0.497 \\ 
> p(B) =0.472 \\
> p(Y|A) =0.259\\
> p(Y|B) =0.249\\
> p(Y|A\cup B) =0.381 \text{ - A or B can cause Y } \\
> p(Y|A\cap B) =0.127 \text{ - A and B can cause Y } \\
> \text{ Now,  }p(Y) = p(Y|A)+p(Y|B) - p(Y|A\cap B) =0.259+0.249 - 0.127 = 0.381
> \end{array}$$

In case if we don't have the joint probability distribution $p(Y|A\cap B)$ =0.127, is there a way to find p(Y) = 0.381?

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: $P(Y)$ should be $P(A)P(Y|A) + P(B)P(Y|B) - P(A\cap B)P(Y | A\cap B)$.

Comment: Proof: \begin{align}P(Y) & = P(A \cap Y) + P(B \cap Y) - P((A \cap B) \cap Y)\\
& = P(A)P(Y|A) + P(B)P(Y|B) + P(A \cap B)P(Y|A \cap B)
\end{align}

Comment: My concern is, I don't know P(Y|A∩B), I just know P(Y|A) and P(Y|B)